# Type lambda that returns a type lambda in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I want to have a type lambda in Scala that returns a type lambda instead of a type.

```
def f[A](implicit ev1: Eq[A], ev2: ClassTag[A])
```

I want to combine these two implicit evidences into one evidence variable. I tried

```
trait Ev2[E1[_], E2[_], T] extends Product2[E1[T], E2[T]] {
  def canEqual(that: Any) = false
}

object Ev2 {
  implicit def ev2[T, E1[_], E2[_]](implicit e1: E1[T], e2: E2[T]) = new Ev2[E1, E2, T] {
    def _1 = e1
    def _2 = e2
  }
}
```

then

```
type &[E1[_], E2[_]] = ({type λ[T] = Ev2[E1, E2, T]})#λ
```

I'd like to write the aforementioned function `f` as

```
def f[A: Eq & ClassTag]
```

However the `&` type lambda I defined does not compile. Is there a way to write such a type lambda that returns a type lambda (of kind `* => *`)?

Comment: If your goal is to simplify line 1, then why wouldn't you just write `def f[A : Eq : ClassTag] = ???`

Comment: @MichaelZajac I'm trying to unify functions with no evidences, with 1, or with 2 evidences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also define `&` as an actual trait with an internal type instead of a type lambda:

```
trait &[E1[_], E2[_]] {
  type λ[T] = Ev2[E1, E2, T]
}
```

Or alternatively as an anonymous trait:

```
type &[E1[_], E2[_]] = { type λ[T] = Ev2[E1, E2, T] }
```

And then use the internal type:

```
def f[A: (Eq & ClassTag)#λ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the best I can do, I suppose.